# Set ms-screenclip protocol handler to Snipping Tool on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, default-settings

Starting with Windows 10 build 1903, the usual Snipping Tool shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> no longer opens the Snipping Tool.

It looks like that this shortcut launches the `ms-screenclip:` protocol which is associated with "Windows Shell Experience Host" application.

I'm looking to either:

- Make <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> launch the Snipping Tool.
- Associate `ms-screenclip:` protocol with the Snipping Tool.

I couldn't find where this shortcut is associated with that protocol so instead I've tried changing the default application for this protocol but unfortunately that functionality has also been dumbed down:

[image]

I've tried manually adding the command using both Registry Editor and [URLProtocolView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/url_protocol_view.html) but that had no effect.

My idea is to either replace "Windows Shell Experience Host" with my command or to register Snipping Tool as an application capable of handling the `ms-screenclip` protocol in order for it to show up in the UWP settings prompt.

Comment: @John I've uninstalled Snip 'n Sketch and I want it to open the legacy Snipping Tool located at %windir%/System32/SnippingTool.exe. The Win+Shift+S currently opens an overlay with five buttons on top which is integrated in the shell (similar effect to Win+R -> `ms-screenclip:`)

Comment: There is no legacy Snipping Tool - it was replaced and removing the new one has caused your issue. Just adopt the new tool, or use SnagIt from TechSmith (a more robust and stable capture tool)

Comment: @John The legacy SnippingTool.exe is still available on 1909 -- check your System32 folder (it shows an ad for Snip 'n Sketch but still works). The screenshot functionality (Win+Shift+S = `ms-screenclip:`) is separate from Snip 'n Sketch (`ms-screensketch:`), try launching both protocols using Win+R and you'll see that `ms-screenclip:` starts Shell Experience Host (the five buttons on top) and `ms-screensketch:` starts Snip 'n Sketch. I want the Win+Shift+S to launch SnippingTool.exe instead of `ms-screenclip:`

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1578218/485444) to resolve **Snip & Sketch** and **ms-screenclip** failure.

It is recommended that you create **Restore Point** before upgrading/reinstalling windows by **Windows Media Creation Tool**

Comment: This is a link-only answer and should include more information. In any case, how would re-installing Windows help, when the problem is by design of Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map the key combination
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
to launch the Snipping Tool:

```
#+s::Run, %windir%\system32\SnippingTool.exe
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

Comment: This works, but it requires running AutoHotkey. It would be great if it's possible to add the "ms-screenclip" capability to Snipping Tool through registry similar to what Edge Deflector does (https://github.com/da2x/EdgeDeflector)

Comment: EdgeDeflector is just another software, same as AutoHotkey.

Comment: It doesn't do remapping itself, the "software" part in it only contains the logic to parse the URL and open it in a preferred browser.

The remapping part is done only through registry by making the program a "microsoft-edge:" protocol handler. I'd prefer to make Snipping Tool (existing software) a handler of the "ms-screenclip:" protocol URL that's being opened when the combination is pressed.

Comment: Unfortunately Ctrl+Backspace cannot be mapped in the registry. Each key can be mapped separately, but not the combination. You can test this by trying to map it with one of the best keyboard mappers - [SharpKeys](https://www.randyrants.com/2021/10/sharpkeys-3-9-3/).

Answer (score 0):

##### In Windows 11 (I do not have Windows 10)

###### How it works (on my computer at least):

Pressing Win+Shift+S starts the "Screen Snipping" tool that *then in turn* starts the "Snip & Sketch" (a.k.a. the Snipping Tool).

###### Alternative ways to start a screenshot without pressing Win + Shift + S:

- Press Win + R and run the command: **ms-screenclip:**
- In a batch script run: **start ms-screenclip:**

###### Make sure that these settings are correct:

Go to "Settings → Apps → Default apps → Choose default apps by protocol", and make sure

- that MS-SCREENSKETCH is set to "Snip & Sketch" (a.k.a. Snipping Tool) **and**
- that MS-SCREENCLIP is set to "Screen Snipping". ***This is very important or else it wont work!***