# Snip & Sketch tool not working - missing ms-screenclip protocol handler

Tags: windows-10

I bought a new computer, installed Windows 10 Pro N on it (version 2004), and now the Snip & Sketch tool isn't working.

When I click the button 'New', it shows the message "You'll need a new app to open this ms-screenclip link". I've tried the link to look for apps in the Microsoft store, but it won't find anything.

[image]

Upon further investigation, I discovered that on my pc, the protocol handler 'ms-screenclip' is not installed, while it is on my laptop. The 'ms-screensketch' protocol is installed, weirdly enough.
[image]

I've tried removing and reinstalling the app multiple times through the Windows store, but it has had no effect. 
Any idea how I can add that protocol handler to my machine?

Cheers,
CJ

---

Answer (score 5):

[This worked for me](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/youll-need-a-new-app-to-open-this-ms-screenclip/44d32d85-aef9-48b9-bff4-c134dd1dd253):

```
DISM /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Windows.Client.ShellComponents~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Comment: Running this command on Windows 10 20H2 returned error 1168: "Element not found".

Comment: I believe there's a way to get DISM to list available components. I suspect maybe the version has changed? I'm on my phone so I can't check at the moment, but that would be my first suspicion

Answer (score 0):

For solving **Snip & Sketch** and **ms-screenclip** failure you should use the [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

Download the application, then follow below steps to repair your windows installation:

1. **Run** application (You need to be an administrator to run this tool)
2. If you accept the license terms, select **Accept**
3. Select **Upgrade this PC now** on "What do you want to do?" screen and then select **Next**
4. Wait until creation tool download last stable version of Windows 10 and it's updates
5. When **Windows 10** is ready to install, you’ll see a recap of what you’ve chosen, and what will be kept through the installation. Select **Change what to keep** to set it to **Keep personal files and apps** to just repair the current installation
6. Select **Install** to run windows installation, remember to **don't turn off your PC during installation**

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 methods suggested here with no response if it worked:

https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/youll-need-a-new-app-to-open-this-ms-screenclip-link.408883/#post-2037453

1. Reset the app
2. Re-register the app
3. Reinstall the app

Borrowing from Alireza Sedghi and this post with a confirmed solution:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/ms-screenclip-link-missing-in-windows/4e6561e7-f3c3-4a1f-bca7-c7c6ede393c8

4. Use the [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to do an "in-place upgrade"
5. You are using the old EXE version of the snipping tool on a server and a message is showing:

[image]

If you click the "Try Snip & Sketch" button while on a server, it will try to take you to the Windows Store which is not available on Windows Server as of Server 2019 and that error referencing ms-screenclip will show.  Solution: don't click the "Try Snip & Sketch" button.  Click "New" instead to use the tool as normal.

Answer (score 0):

##### For those trying to get this to work in Windows 11 (I do not have Windows 10):

###### How this works (on my computer at least):

Pressing Win+Shift+S starts the "Screen Snipping" tool that *then in turn* starts the "Snip & Sketch" (a.k.a. the Snipping Tool).

###### Alternative ways to start a screenshot without pressing Win + Shift + S:

- Press Win + R and run the command: **ms-screenclip:**
- In a batch script run: **start ms-screenclip:**

###### Make sure that these settings are correct:

Go to "Settings → Apps → Default apps → Choose default apps by protocol", and make sure

- that MS-SCREENSKETCH is set to "Snip & Sketch" (a.k.a. Snipping Tool) **and**
- that MS-SCREENCLIP is set to "Screen Snipping". ***This is very important or else it wont work!***